# Precise Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c, string, memory-management, realloc

I would like to dynamically allocate memory for an input string whose size is unknown at the time of input,with exact precision, i.e.
if the string is "stack" I would like to allocate 6 bytes only.

I guess the only way is to keep on increasing the upper limit of the array depending on the input but I am unable to figure out the piece of code.

Comment: `malloc(6)` would allocate 6 bytes. But, memory allocators never allocate memory with byte precision internally. Bookkeeping exact size would cost more, and it would be slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strdup()` is your friend.

```
char *p = strdup("stack");
```

Comment: Strdup() is great but is there a way to do it without using string functions?

Comment: @YasasveeAtreya, you can use the strlen/malloc/strcpy answers below or you can roll your own using only malloc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to measure the length of the string and then allocate.

Length:

```
int len = strlen(input_string);
```

allocate memory

```
char *p = malloc (sizeof(char) * len + 1) ;
```

then save it

```
strcpy (p, input_string);
```